# Define ansible vars dict, where variable B includes variable A from the same dict

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

is it somehow possible to define the var in YAML vars file like the following:

```
nodeJs:
  version : "10.x"
  url     : "xxx.com/{{ nodeJS['version'] }}"
  script  : "runme.sh"
```

I believe it is possible, as Python itself allows such kind of reference:

```
nodeJS = {"version": "10.x", "url": "xxx.com/"+nodeJS['version'], "script":"runme.sh"}
Output:
nodeJS
Out[34]: {'script': 'runme.sh', 'url': 'xxx.com/10.x', 'version': '10.x'}
```

I know i can simply define variables like:

```
nodeJSversion = "10.x"
nodeJSurl = "xxx.com/{{ nodeJSversion  }}"
```

but it doesn't suit

Comment: I don't think there is a way to resolve the vars dynamically. The playbook assumes it's a string & just prints the string rather resolving vars.
Why don't you have a jinja template for the vars, resolve the template & load the vars file in the playbook???

Comment: I want to refer to these vars in different tasks from playbook, currently it is like:
`- name          : Download Node.js script
  get_url       :
    url         : "{{ njUrl }}"
    dest        : "{{ ansible_env.HOME}}/{{ njScript }}"
  register      : nodejs_download

- name          : Add Node.js PPA
  shell         : |
    bash "{{ ansible_env.HOME}}/{{ njScript }}"
  register      : njresult
  become        : yes
  when          : nodejs_download.changed`
imo, vars like nodeJS['version'], nodeJS['url'] are more human readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so that can be done directly. You can use the template module of ansible declare the variable inside a yaml file. define the variable to replaced in extra vars or in any of the inventory files